# How Can I Delete These Ubuntu Boot Entries

Tags: boot, uefi

Long story short, tried to install Ubuntu on my new PC but ran into two huge bugs with the installer that almost broke my computer. Asked for help on here and whilst someone did spend some of their time trying to help me, we couldn't fix it.

So I'm done, I'm going back to Windows.
I've tried to follow other guides on this site, but the commands needed for my use case seem to be different and I don't know what they are.

I'm using efibootmgr to remove the boot entries and this is what I get back with:

`sudo efibootmgr`

```
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* UEFI: PXE IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0002* UEFI: PXE IP6 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0003* Hard Drive
Boot0004* ubuntu
Boot0005* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0006* ubuntu
Boot0007* UEFI: Lexar JumpDrive 1100, Partition 1
Boot0008* USB
```

I want to remove the two Ubuntu entries and the duplicate Windows Boot Manager entry at Boot0005.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: So remove them if you like. What is the problem?

Comment: "but the commands needed for my use case seem to be different and I don't know what they are" - I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What commands are you asking about? If you are sure you don't need `0004` entry. remove it by `sudo efibootmgr -Bb 0004`. But make sure you can boot Windows without grub first.

Comment: Thank you Pilot, I've done it thanks to the command you posted. Appreciate it man!